# How can I display a negative symbol in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, silverlight

I want to display a negative symbol from a string in .NET.  I want a string that represents an equation that looks something like this:

7--5=12

But when displayed, I want the 2nd minus sign to be slightly raised so it looks more natural as a negative sign instead of just 2 minus signs in a row.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're writing educational software, I hope it's deliberate that the equation here is false :-)

Comment: haha, oops, I should fix that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Unicode character [`SUPERSCRIPT MINUS (U+207B)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207b/index.htm) `⁻`.

For example:

> ```
> 7-⁻5 = 13
> ```

**EDIT**: Or, with a [`MINUS SIGN (U+2212)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) `⁻` for the minus:

> ```
> 7 − ⁻5 = 13
> ```

Comment: It's what was asked for... but gaw that's ugly :)

Comment: it would look better if you used a MINUS SIGN (U+2212) or en dash surrounded by spaces for the first minus

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if theres a character for what you want but a simple solution (and one that would be easily understood and implemented) would be to surround your negative number in brackets:

```
7 - (-5) = 13
```

Comment: This is the most typographically robust solution.

Comment: This is good, except the target audience is for elementary students.  I think they will understand the raised minus sign over this format.  Otherwise, this is what I would probably do.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that you're using unicode you can use a *true* minus sign, "−" (U+2212) rather than a hyphen-minus, "-" (U+002D).  Just be aware that it's not ASCII compatible

Here's your example showing them:

> 7 - −5=13

Also, here's some fun wiki-articles on all sorts of dash-hyphen-minus lines:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minus_sign#Character_codes

Answer (score 2):

This is a great resource on format strings in C#:
[SteveX Compiled - Format Strings](http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

You can choose how a negative number is displayed by using a range expression for your format string.  It's in the format:

```
{0:<PositiveFormat>;<NegativeFormat>;<ZeroFormat>}
```

For example, this is how to display a negative number in parenthesis and the word "Zero" for 0:

```
{0:#;(#);Zero}
```

Using this technique, I think you can try it with the superscript version of negative (which is ascii code U+207B) in the negative format string.

```
{0:#;⁻#;Zero}
```

HTH, Anderson

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally in math typography you use an en dash U+2013 or minus U+2212 (but not a hyphen!) for both binary (subtraction) and unary (negation) minus, and they are differentiated with spacing (spaces before and after a binary minus, no space between a unary minus and the number it negates).

But if you want to further distinguish the unary, I'd recommend substituting the superscript minus U+207B (but keep the spacing around the subtraction minus):

7 − ⁻5 = 13

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode character U+2212 (Minus Sign): 7-−5=13

In the font I'm using, the minus sign is displayed slightly raised relative to the dash. Your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode "superscript minus" http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207b/index.htm

```
char c = '\u207b';
```